# Is there any way to order result by column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table with many columns.

```
id|Date      |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|...                |col500|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1|01.10.2019| 152|  99|   0|1598|  48|  filled with zeros|     1|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 2|02.10.2019|  12| 344|  19|2544|   3|  filled with zeros|   152|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
....
```

Is it possible to order column

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date = '02.10.2019' ORDER BY COLUMNS

and get result like this

```
id|Date       |col4|col2|col500|col3|col1|col5|...              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 2|02.10.2019 |2544| 344|   152|  19|  12|   3|filled with zeros
```

Comment: No. The result set columns are fixed. (And decided at compile time, before data is read.)

Comment: How does it matter ? Ordering within columns does not matter at all, especially when you take the query result out as an associative array. Moreover, the moment you have multiple columns having similar attributes, it reeks of a really bad design.

Comment: Short answer no.  A table with 500+ columns - oh dear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order by columns value, as Madhur Bhaiya and P.Salmon said, may be your table is not properly designed, and you are probably speaking of **rows**, and not of **columns**.
Instead of a table with columns `ID/ Date/ col1/ col2/ ... / col500`, perhaps you need a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
pk integer not null primary key default autoincrement,
id integer not null,
dt date not null,
xxx_id integer,
value integer);
```

where XXX_ID represent the column position in your old table (may be an identifier of single record, I don't know what you are using this table for).
Now you have to insert the values:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (1, '2019-10-01', 152);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (1, '2019-10-01', 99);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (1, '2019-10-01', 0);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (1, '2019-10-01', 1592);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (1, '2019-10-01', 48);
....
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (2, '2019-10-02', 12);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (2, '2019-10-02', 344);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (2, '2019-10-02', 19);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, date, value) VALUES (2, '2019-10-02', 2544);
...
```

And the answer to your question becomes very easy, something like

```
select * from tbl 
where id = 1 AND date = '2019-10-01'
order by value
```

Last point: you can decide to insert records with ZERO value, or skip them, or insert them with `NULL` value. It depends on what is the goal of the table.

Comment: It will throw error on 2nd insert since the table has `primary key` as **id**. Just remove that or add another column for `primary key`

Comment: @James you are right, I have modified the answer. Actually it would be better to have a main table (where ID is the `primary key` and DATE is a field -- it is wrong to repeat the value of date on each record), and the field ID in table TBL should refer (as a Foreign Key) to this main table. But I wrote only a short answer, and we don't know what SALIH AKIN has to do.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Feacio, jarlh, Madhur Bhaiya, P.Salmon and James. The purpose of the table will be calculate daily repetition of input and output(I/O) signals read from PLC(Programmable Logic Controller). I have table for online state of I/O signals and trigger after update and check when signal change status from 0 to 1. After then add +1 of last value in archive tbl. In short, I will prepare archive table like you propose. Best regards.

Comment: @SalihAKIN you are welcome. And please _accept the answer_ if you like it